# Statments inside `let` inside `for` loop won't both run at the same time

Tags: clojure, neo4j

I'm trying to import data from StackOverflow to Neo4j using clojure and the neocons library.  Excuse me for being a bit of a newbie.

Here's my main function in Leiningen:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]

  (let [neo4j-conn  (nr/connect "http://localhost:7777/db/data/")]

    (cypher/tquery neo4j-conn "MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() DELETE n, r")

    (for [page (range 1 6)]
      (let [data (parse-string (stackoverflow-get-questions page))
            questions (data "items")
            has-more (data "has_more")
            question-ids (map #(%1 "question_id") questions)
            answers ((parse-string (stackoverflow-get-answers question-ids)) "items")]
        (map #(import-question %1 neo4j-conn) questions)
        (map #(import-answer %1 neo4j-conn) answers)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I've defined `import-question` and `import-answer` functions and those work fine independently.  In fact, what's weird is I can remove either one of those `import-*` lines and the other will work just fine.

Can anybody see if I'm doing something simple that's wrong?

Comment: Your specific question is not a duplicate, but the answer definitely is. Both `map` and `for` are lazy, and will do nothing at all unless you consume their results. The first `map` call ends up being a noop because there is no way for anything to consume it's output. Try wrapping the `for` and at least the first `map` call in a call to `dorun`.

Comment: The lazy-bug bites us all (or at least me) from time to time. PS: @noisesmith that's long enough to put in the answer. there's nothing wrong with duplicate answers to distinct questions on SO. and It will help people who wander here from searches if there is an accepted answer.

Comment: OK, thanks. Making it an answer then.

Comment: @noisesmith you should mention `doseq`, which is really what OP wants. Realizing a sequence for side effects only is bad style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `map` and `for` are lazy, and will do nothing at all unless you consume their results.

The first `map` call ends up being a noop because there is no way for anything to consume it's output. Try wrapping the `for` and at least the first map call in a call to `dorun`, or `doall` if you plan on consuming the result.

Also, you can replace `for` with `doseq`, which is identical except that it returns nil, eagerly consumes its input, and can contain multiple forms in its body.

Here is what your code could look like using `doseq`:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [neo4j-conn (nr/connect "http://localhost:7777/db/data/")]
    (cypher/tquery neo4j-conn "MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() DELETE n, r")
    (doseq [page (range 1 6)
            :let [data (parse-string (stackoverflow-get-questions page))
                  questions (data "items")
                  has-more (data "has_more")
                  question-ids (map #(%1 "question_id") questions)
                  answers ((parse-string (stackoverflow-get-answers question-ids)) "items")]]
      (doseq [q questions]
        (import-question q neo4j-conn))
      (doseq [a answers]
        (import-answer a neo4j-conn)))))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Definitely good to have this even if it's a duplicate.  I search a lot and couldn't find any answer, so we're increasing the landing space for users with this issue, I suppose